# SystemCtl Enable Seems to Depend on File Name

Tags: 18.04, systemd

I have been trying to create a service file that would let me run ElasticSearch on an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

I have the following two files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 114 Apr 14 13:43 /lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch1.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 114 Apr 14 13:51 /lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service
```

They are identical copies of each other, containing

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/elasticsearch

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, `sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch1` produces

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/elasticsearch1.service → /lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch1.service.
```

Whereas, `sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch` produces

```
Synchronizing state of elasticsearch.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable elasticsearch
update-rc.d: error: elasticsearch Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

What is the issue here? I had a more involved file which was getting the same error. In trying to debug it, I distilled it to a simple case like this, which baffles me.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was?

Comment: @Baumflaum I do not recall exactly. I might have changed the ElasticSearch version or something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I fixed a very similar problem by deleting a stray /etc/init.d/myservice that was named the same as /var/systemd/system/myservice.service.